# Cannot add App to Facebook pages

Tags: facebook

Since today, I cannot add new apps to Facebook pages.

Normally I create an app, go to the app-page and click on "Add to my page":

[image]

The link to the add page was [this](https://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=%3Capplication_id%3E), but it's not working anymore.

Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Check this page tab tutorial.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/)

Comment: no, because i can't open to the application page, so i can't click on  "add to my page"

Comment: ok its working with the 2nd solution:
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=<app_id>&next=

thanks :)

Comment: What did you put in the next parameter? i cant work out which domain they want in there? @Tom

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little helper page to do this until Facebook fixes it themselves: http://stickybeat.se/addapp/

Answer (score 0):

This [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/add_to_page/) might be more direct on what you are looking for.  It gives an example of using the Facebook api to add a page as well as the dialog method.